# 'libpng', converting a PNG file from grayscale to RGB (to just one of the channels)

Tags: rgb, grayscale, libpng

I have a piece of source code that reads and writes images to PNG files. However, it only writes the images as grayscale, precisely just black and white.

Now, how do I modify it such that it would write to one of the channels in RGB (R or G or B is fine)?

Is there a short tutorial about that pixel manipulation with [libpng](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libpng)?

Answer (score -1):

It isn't small or nice written tutorial, but always something:

http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng-1.2.5-manual.html

Comment: No upvote for that; while it probably does have useful things in it, it's too much to read without some pointers for what to search for.

Comment: It's also pretty old.  The libpng distributions include libpng.3 and libpng-manual.txt (current version is 1.6.10 and legacy version 1.2.52).  But at any rate, libpng doesn't offer the particular transformation you are asking for.  It can transform a 1-channel grayscale image to 3-channel RGB (all three channels identical).

Comment: People browse answers to get relevant details.  They don't come to stackoverflow to see answers that say read the documentation! Links grow stale, and "read the manual" might be something you mention in comment, is NOT an answer. Answers are supposed to show exactly how to resolve the question asked by providing techniques, descriptions, pertinent examples, not just say go and read a novel.